# Angular - Populating Form from Firebase Results In Duplicates

Tags: angular, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore

I'm populating a form based on a query.  In this case, there should be two entries, but I'm getting a duplicate:

```
  get childrenForm() {
    return this.recordForm.get('children') as FormArray;
  }

     // Get all students associated with the current record.
    const query = this.afs.collection('students', ref => ref.where('recordId', '==', this.currentRecordId));
    this.subscriptions.push(
       query.valueChanges()
       .subscribe(students => {
        console.log(`MD: RecordFormPage -> populateForm -> students`, students);
        students.forEach((child: any) => {
          const timestamp = child.dob.seconds;
          const date = new Date(timestamp * 1000);
          const childData = this.fb.group({
            fname: child.fname,
            lname: child.lname,
            dob: date,
            grade: child.grade,
            gender: child.gender,
            race: child.race,
            id: child.id
          });
          this.childrenForm.push(childData);
        });
      })
    );
```

Note duplicate Delvin Carrington entry:
[image]

You'll notice in the console that `valueChanges()` emits the first entry in the data base, then emits the first entry + second entry, thus producing three results:
[image]

So I believe that If there is an appropriate way to wait until `valueChanges()` has all the data, then only at that point, emit and/or push the data to `this.chidrenForm` - that should fix it.  Knowing that a subscription to `valueChanges()` will not fire its `onComplete` method.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you push to the form every time there is a change, you will end up with duplicates. Why don't you use AngularFire and a two-way data biding to Firebase instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could just clear the form everytime it runs with:

```
this.childrenForm.clear();
```

prior to your forEach

Comment: Thank you.  That works.  I'm still curious as to how one would wait until `valueChanges()` obtains all the data since `onComplete` never fires on a  subscription for `valueChanges()` but that's probably best served as separate question.

Comment: not sure, don't really use firebase and I'm not sure why it would emit the data in this fashion. if there are 3 items does it emit 3 times?

Comment: if there were 3 it would emit the payload as `item1`, then `item1 +  item2`, then finally `item1 + item2+ item3`  That last screen shot you see is the console.log of the `students` payload from the subscription: `.subscribe(students => {...}`

Comment: weird. I suppose you could put `debounceTime(500)` or something on the stream to ignore things that arrive within half a second of eachother if they all arrive in very quick succession

Comment: The issue there is you're assuming that the DB transactions would complete in X amount of microseconds.  If latency beyond 500ms, then I imagine the bug would occur.

Comment: yea, you'd still need the clear but you could avoid some of the filling / clearing by debouncing it